# HTML5 canvas creating oscillating motion

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote the following HTML5 canvas code on a text editor:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var canvasPlanet = document.getElementById("canvasPlanet");
  var contextPlanet = canvasPlanet.getContext("2d");
  var canvasBG = document.getElementById("canvasBackground");
  var contextBG = canvasBackground.getContext("2d");

  var change = .6;
  var interval = 33;
  var radius = 0;
  var radiusMin = 100;
  var numStars1 = 2000;
  var numStars2 = 400;
  var numStars3 = 30;
  var planetSize = 12;
  var imageCount = 0;
  var xPos = canvasPlanet.width / 2;
  var yPos = canvasPlanet.height / 2;
  var angle = 0;
  var radiusMax = 175;
  var colorStar1 = "white";
  var colorStar2 = "gray";
  var colorStar3 = "darkgray";
  var sunSize = 45;
  var imageQuant = 2;

  contextBG.fillStyle = "black";
  contextBG.fillRect(0, 0, canvasBG.width, canvasBG.height);

  for (var n = 0; n < numStars1; n++) {
    var xStar = Math.random() * canvasBG.width;
    var yStar = Math.random() * canvasBG.height;
    contextBG.fillStyle = colorStar2;
    contextBG.fillRect(xStar, yStar, 1, 1);
  }
  for (var n = 0; n < numStars2; n++) {
    var xStar = Math.random() * canvasBG.width;
    var yStar = Math.random() * canvasBG.height;
    contextBG.fillStyle = colorStar2;
    contextBG.fillRect(xStar, yStar, 2, 2);
  }
  for (var n = 0; n < numStars3; n++) {
    var xStar = Math.random() * canvasBG.width;
    var yStar = Math.random() * canvasBG.height;
    contextBG.fillStyle = colorStar3;
    contextBG.fillRect(xStar, yStar, 3, 3);
  }

  var planet = new Image();
  planet.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/future/images/3/34/PLANET.png/revision/latest?cb=20120319180022";
  var sun = new image();
  sun.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/vsbattles/images/c/ca/Render_sun.png/revision/latest?cb=20160310013337";

  sun.onload() {
    contextBG.drawImage(sun, 200, 175, sunSize, sunSize);

    imageCount++;

    if (imageCount == imageQuant)

    {
      var intervalID = setInterval(drawPlanet, interval)
    }
  }

  planet.onload = function() {
    contextPlanet.translate(xPos, yPos);

    imageCount++;

    if (imageCount == imageQuant)

    {
      var intervalID = setInterval(drawPlanet, interval)
    }
  }

  function drawPlanet() {
    contextPlanet.clearRect(-canvasPlanet.width / 2, -canvasPlanet.height / 2, canvasPlanet.width, canvasPlanet.height);

    var angleR = (Math.Pi / 180) * angle;
    var calcAS = radiusMax * Math.sin(angleR);
    var calcBC = radiusMax * Math.cos(angleR);
    radius = (radiusMax * radiusMin) / Math.sqrt((calcAS * calcAS) + (calcBC * calcBC));

    contextPlanet.rotate(((Math.PI) / 180 * ) - change);
    angle = angle + change;

    cantextPlanet.drawImage(planet, radius, 0, planetSize, planetSize);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvasPlanet" width="400" height="400" style="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; 
                    left:auto; top:auto; z-index: 2">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
  <canvas id="canvasBackground" width="400" height="400" style="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; 
                    left:auto; top:auto; z-index: 1">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
</div>
```

The code is supposed to create an oscillating motion which displays a planet orbiting around the sun in space with lots of stars, but the canvas is not display for some reason. If anyone can tell me what i did wrong, i would appreciate it. Please and thank you,

Comment: Well I just hit "run snippet" and get greeted with the error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token `{`'. Maybe you should fix your syntax first?

Comment: error in line:54 js   `sun.onload() {` change to `sun.onload = function() {` and  line:86 js `contextPlanet.rotate(((Math.PI) / 180 * ) - change);` you forgot what you want to multiply

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the code to display the canvas and the objects.

```js
    window.onload = function() {
    
      var canvasPlanet = document.getElementById("canvasPlanet");
      var contextPlanet = canvasPlanet.getContext("2d");
      var canvasBG = document.getElementById("canvasBackground");
      var contextBG = canvasBackground.getContext("2d");
    
      var change = .006;
      var interval = 33;
      var radius = 1000;
      var radiusMin = 100;
      var numStars1 = 2000;
      var numStars2 = 400;
      var numStars3 = 30;
      var planetSize = 12;
      var imageCount = 0;
      var xPos = canvasPlanet.width/2;
      var yPos = canvasPlanet.height/2;
      var angle = 0;
      var radiusMax = 175;
      var colorStar1 = "white";
      var colorStar2 = "gray";
      var colorStar3 = "darkgray";
      var sunSize = 45;
      var imageQuant = 2;
    
      contextBG.fillStyle = "black";
      contextBG.fillRect(0, 0, canvasBG.width, canvasBG.height);
    
         for(var n=0; n<numStars1; n++)
         {
            var xStar = Math.random()*canvasBG.width;
            var yStar = Math.random()*canvasBG.height;
            contextBG.fillStyle = colorStar2;
            contextBG.fillRect(xStar, yStar, 1, 1);
         }
         for(var n=0; n<numStars2; n++)
         {
            var xStar = Math.random()*canvasBG.width;
            var yStar = Math.random()*canvasBG.height;
            contextBG.fillStyle = colorStar2;
            contextBG.fillRect(xStar, yStar, 2, 2);
         }
         for(var n=0; n<numStars3; n++)
         {
            var xStar = Math.random()*canvasBG.width;
            var yStar = Math.random()*canvasBG.height;
            contextBG.fillStyle = colorStar3;
            contextBG.fillRect(xStar, yStar, 3, 3);
         }
      var planet = new Image();
      planet.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/future/images/3/34/PLANET.png/revision/latest?cb=20120319180022";
      var sun = new Image();
      sun.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/vsbattles/images/c/ca/Render_sun.png/revision/latest?cb=20160310013337";
    
      sun.onload = function()
      {
        contextBG.drawImage(sun, 200, 175, sunSize, sunSize);
    
        imageCount ++;
    
        if(imageCount == imageQuant)
    
          {var intervalID = setInterval(drawPlanet, interval)}
      }
    
      planet.onload = function ()
      {
        contextPlanet.translate(xPos, yPos);
    
        imageCount ++;
    
        if(imageCount == imageQuant)
    
          {var intervalID = setInterval(drawPlanet, interval)}
      }
    
     function drawPlanet()
      {
         contextPlanet.clearRect(-canvasPlanet.width / 2, -canvasPlanet.height / 2, canvasPlanet.width, canvasPlanet.height);
    
        var angleR = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
        var calcAS = radiusMax * Math.sin(angleR);
        var calcBC = radiusMax * Math.cos(angleR);
        radius = (radiusMax * radiusMin) / Math.sqrt((calcAS * calcAS) + (calcBC * calcBC));
    
        contextPlanet.rotate(((Math.PI) / 180) - change);
        angle = angle + change;
    
        contextPlanet.drawImage(planet, radius, 0, planetSize, planetSize);
    
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <canvas id    ="canvasPlanet" width="400" height="400" 
            style ="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; 
                    left:auto; top:auto; z-index: 2">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id    ="canvasBackground" width="400" height="400" 
            style ="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; 
                    left:auto; top:auto; z-index: 1">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```